# ArrayList from Java to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

We have the following JSON string converted from a list of objects with JSON:

```
jsonUserDataRecsString = [{"G_ID1":1,"G_ID2":2,"G_ID3":3,"NAME":"k1"},{"G_ID1":4,"G_ID2":5,"G_ID3":6,"NAME":"k2"}]
```

When we pass this JSON as parameter to a JavaScript function, this string value is listed as follows:

```
finalString : [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

How could we pass this `jsonUserDataRecsString` as it is, that is as:

```
[{"G_ID1":1,"G_ID2":2,"G_ID3":3,"NAME":"k1"},"G_ID1":4,"G_ID2":5,"G_ID3":6,"NAME":"k2"}]
```

? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The variable you are showing in fact is not a string. It is an array containing two objects.
Depending on how you get this array you could put a single quote at the beginning and at the end:

```
jsonUserDataRecsString = '[{"G_ID1":1,"G_ID2":2,"G_ID3":3,"NAME":"k1"},{"G_ID1":4,"G_ID2":5,"G_ID3":6,"NAME":"k2"}]'
```

or a more universal way

```
JSON.stringify(jsonUserDataRecsString)
```

which will stringify any javascript object to string being able to convert it back to an object via

```
JSON.parse(objectJsonString)
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution is as follows:
We need to call the stringify function at the javascript side.
JSON.stringify(jsonUserDataRecsString)